# Vulcan detecting GPU on TTY but not on gnome

Tags: debian, gnome, gpu, amd, vulkan

I am on Debian 11

I have a program that works by overriding tty1. So when starting my computer, the program runs right away. This works fine, but I use Gnome as my GUI to develop and test the program. When running the program while in Gnome I get:

```
WARNING: lavapipe is not a conformant vulkan implementation, testing use only.
Segmentation fault
```

Running vulkaninfo --summary over tty outputs

```
Devices:
========
GPU0:
        apiVersion         = 420641 (1.2.145)
        driverVersion      = 83898373
        vendorID           = 0x10002
        deviceID           = 0x1508
        deviceType         = PHYSICAL_DEVICE_TYPE_INTEGRATED_GPU
        deviceName         = AMD_RADV_RAVEN *ACO)
        driverID           = DRIVER_ID_MESA_RADV
        driverName         = radv
        driverInfo         = Mesa 20.3.5 (ACO)
        conformanceVersion = 1.2.3.0 

GPU1:
        apiVersion         = 4194306 (1.0.2)
        driverVersion      = 1 (0x0001)
        vendorID           = 0x10005
        deviceID           = 0x0000
        deviceType         = PHYSICAL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU
        deviceName         = llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.1, 256 bits)
        driverID           = DRIVER_ID_MESA_LLVMPIPE
        driverName         = llvmpipe
```

but running vulkaninfo --summary over gnome outputs

```
Devices:
========
GPU0:
        apiVersion         = 4194306 (1.0.2)
        driverVersion      = 1 (0x0001)
        vendorID           = 0x10005
        deviceID           = 0x0000
        deviceType         = PHYSICAL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU
        deviceName         = llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.1, 256 bits)
        driverID           = DRIVER_ID_MESA_LLVMPIPE
        driverName         = llvmpipe
        driverInfo         = Mesa 20.3.5 (LLVM 11.0.1)
        conformanceVersion = 1.0.0.0
        driverInfo         = Mesa 20.3.5 (LLVM 11.0.1)
        conformanceVersion = 1.0.0.0
```

So I can see that in Gnome it's just using my CPU. Is there any way to configure vulkan to also use my GPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to answer my own question:

I ran

`lspci -k`

to check if Gnome recognized my GPU and I saw  my GPU there and its kernel driver.

So I realized the problem might be from Vulkan itself so then I ran

`ls /usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/`

which gave me the output

`intel_icd.x86_64.json  lvp_icd.x86_64.json  radeon_icd.x86_64.json`

`radeon_icd.x86_64.json` is the installable client driver for my AMD GPU

I then ran

`export VK_ICD_FILENAMES=/usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/radeon_icd.x86_64.json`

and then ran my program and it worked.